# Read sonarqube report in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

Hi all I have integrated Jenkins with SonarQube and the project generates a Jacoco code coverage report which is read by SonarQube. I need help to
cancel the pull request if coverage is not met.

Is there a way for Jenkins to read the SonarQube values or if Jenkins can communicate with SonarQube?

Answer (score 0):

Will the [Sonarqube build breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) do the job? *This plugin will mark the build failed if the project fails its quality gate or uses a forbidden configuration*

P.S. to answer the remarks: Quality Gate is requirements for metrics - for example, you can say *Minimum test coverage 60%*. If that is not met this build job is red and the build stops.

Comment: The actual problem is I have to run Intg Tests after the project is deployed in a QA envt.  If the coverage is not met by SonarQube, I need to revert the deploy.                                                                                
                                                                                                                
    For now I am thinking of running IntgTests in a Temp Server, if the coverage is fine then deploy to QA else do not deploy to QA.

Comment: So if the Jenkins for the temp server can query SonarQube it can decide to deploy or not. Please let me know if the problem statement is not clear

Comment: SonarQube has REST Api I am analysing if Jenkins can invoke SonarQube REST APi and decide wether to deploy or not

Comment: That's what the plugin will do for you, but you can do it yourself if you weish.